# Require failing with bundled gem using rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I'm currently trying to include a gem for fuzzy string matching into my Rails project and am getting an error when I actually try and use it, and would love any suggestions as to where to look to track down the missing link.

In my GemFile:

```
gem 'fuzzy-string-match'
```

Which shows up in my GemFile.lock after doing a bundle install:

```
fuzzy-string-match (0.9.5)
```

But whenever I try and use it in my project, I get an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant FuzzyStringMatch
```

I have gotten it to work if I manually require it in my model:

```
require 'fuzzystringmatch'
```

But my understanding is that bundler should be taking care of that behind the scenes. Is there a good way to debug and see what bundler is actually doing to understand why this is missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention that will allow you to skip the `require` statement will only work
when the name of the gem (`fuzzy-string-match`) match the name of the file at the root of the lib directory [(`fuzzystringmatch.rb`)](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match/blob/master/lib/fuzzystringmatch.rb) of the gem project. That's called the  gem's main file ([source](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html)). In this case it does not match.

To avoid the repetition of the `require` statement, you might do the following:

```
gem 'fuzzy-string-match', :require => "fuzzystringmatch"
```